# I edited but forgot to vote to remain open a question in the review queue, is there a way to do it now? Would it make any difference if I did?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I'd edited [a question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43664/12102) from the review queue for close votes, but I forgot to click the "Leave Open" button.

Is there some way I can add my Leave Open vote now? I've poked around in [metaFAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/303080) but nothing about how to do what I want.

And if there was and I did, would it make any difference?

[image: Leave Open]

Comment: I think if you edit it, it's implied that you would like it to stay open. All the leave open vote does is leave a note in the review log. It doesn't counter the close votes.

Comment: @called2voyage that's exactly what I needed to know, though I didn't realize it at the time. I've updated my question accordingly; I'm not sure the links in FAQ make this so clear at least in such plain language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not make a difference. Once you edit a question from the queue, it [boots it from the close queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162058/228367). So now no more queue actions on the question can occur, even if you were a user who hadn't taken a queue action on the question.